# Ctrl-Shift-Arrow not working in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have looked at the different solutions but none work or they are not applicable.  This happened in the middle of an Excel session. I can use Ctrl-Shift+Arrow to select but this does not work in a formula.

Example I have a range of data from B2:B14 in C2 I type =sum( then position the cursor on B2 and hit Ctrl-Shift-ArrowDown.  Normally this results in C2 = sum(B2:B14) instead I get sum(B2) and the array from C2 all the way to last cell in column C2 are selected.

Scroll lock is not on, Lotus compatibility is off, executed Office repair. Nothing helps.

Any suggestions most welcome

Answer (score 1):

I figured that the problem appeared after installing an Add-In (Name Manager from http://www.jkp-ads.com/OfficeMarketPlaceNM-EN.asp).  I have used Name Manager with Excel 2013 without a problem. The Add-In does not have any keyboard shortcuts that I am aware of. After disabling Name Manager Ctrl-Shift-Arrow works again in formulas. Note that Ctrl-Shift-Arrow worked to select a range with Name Manger installed, the problem only happened when using the key combination inside a formula.

I have left a comment for jkp-ads.com describing the problem.

Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how to make this work. 
open excel -> Options -> Advanced -> Lotus compatibility -> Uncheck transition navigation keys.
enjoy!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

Type `=SUM(`

Move Cursur over `B2` and click.

Then Hold just SHIFT and press down once, Keep holding SHIFT,

Then you can press CTRL and Down (still holding SHIFT) to select the rest of the column/array etc.

Comment: Thank   you for your answer but it did not solve the problem.  My data is ins E8:E17,  When I use in G5 sum( and then follow your instructions I get =sum(E8+G4:G1048576.  Not what I intended of course.

Comment: How are you getting a '+' In there ?

Comment: It appears as this after executing the keystrokes you suggested. I have found the problem see answer to my question.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @FiliepSamyn no problem :) if it helped please accept this as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where CTRL Shift DOWN arrow didn't work, within Excel, to select a range of data. I tried all the proposed solutions without success. I was also using the "Youtube Music" app while running Excel. It turned out that the "Youtube Music" app bound my CTRL Shift DOWN key combination, so the key combination didn't work in excel. I simply had to close the "Youtube Music" app for the (CTRL Shift DOWN arrow) functionality to return to Excel.

I suggest you close any apps that you're running and see whether the functionality returns.